# Display sunset and sunrise library in 12 hr format

Tags: javascript

I am using a tiny library that extends JavaScripts Date() class to calculate sunrise, and sunset. The library can be found here: https://github.com/TriggerTrap/sun-js

when I make a call:

```
var sunset = new Date().sunset(lat, lon);

alert(sunset);
```

I get the out put:

```
Tue May 12 2015 18:36:20 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

I've been trying fruitlessly to get this in a 12hr format so instead of 18:36 I would see 6:36 (without seconds. Ive also been trying to strip away the day, and date so that only the time, 6:36 in this case, shows.

Any ideas on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `Date`s have a `toLocaleString` method which does this:

```
alert(sunset.toLocaleTimeString('en-US')); // en-US uses 12 hour format
```

For example:

```js
// always in 12 hour format
document.body.innerHTML = (new Date).toLocaleString("en-US");
```

Comment: I was looking for something like that. Thanks!

Comment: i was thinking locale, but the format does tend to vary a bit between browsers. it might be worth loading up moment.js if consistency is important.

Comment: aside: `(new Date).toLocaleString` == `new Date().toLocaleString` and uses parens on the constructor like doug says we should...

Comment: @dandavis when you do `new Date().toLocaleString` it can be confusing to new users (at least in my anecdotal experience) since it's not obvious if the `new` apples to the `Date` or to the returned value by `toLocaleString`. As for the moment remark - good point. I'll look for a polyfill and if I can't find one I'll recommend it.

Comment: Using `Intl` is also a possible alternative with a polyfill but I didn't suggest it since it's longer. Worth pointing out https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js .

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: fair enough; `(new Date())` is just fugly... i was using localeString a lot until it i noticed it was messing up my grid column widths in firefox. there are lots of small date formatters out there, or even just a custom stitching of several date methods would suffice if moment was too much for such a simple task...

Comment: if i were to use  `alert(sunset.toLocaleTimeString('en-US'));` how could I subtract 15 minutes before displaying the alert?

Comment: @NicklK step 1) search stack overflow for "how to subtract 15 minutes from a Date object", step 2) enter first result (I checked), step 3) apply the solution there step 4) call `.toLocaleTimeString` on the result :)